# Authorization Role/Policy Attributes Not Working In .Net Core 3

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity, .net-core-3.0

I've had no luck getting any Role or Policy attributes working in .Net Core 3. I started my project with the .Net Core Angular starter project with authentication.
I figured this was something to do with the new .AddDefault methods so I have simplified it as much as I possibly can and it still doesn't work.

Here is my policy:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("IsAdmin", policy =>
        policy.RequireClaim("role", "admin"));
});
```

Here is my controller:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "IsAdmin")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AdminController : Controller 
{
    ...
```

I made a custom Profile service that adds the claim to the token,

```
var claims = new List<Claim>();

if (await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Admin"))
{
    claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Role, "admin"));
}

context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(claims);
```

Inside my access token (from jwt.io):

[image]

Other parts of configure services:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

...

services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

The plain `[Authorize]` tag is working fine with the access token on other controllers.

When I hit this controller with the access token I get a `403` response

What am I missing that is preventing this from working?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I try your code and find that the `role` claim key has been transformed to the [standard Role ClaimsType](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/a10890f4ffe0fadf090c922578ba0e606ebdd16c/src/System.Security.Claims/src/System/Security/Claims/ClaimTypes.cs#L27) : `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role`

[image]

So using `ClaimTypes.Role` will fix the problem:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options => { 
    options.AddPolicy("IsAdmin", policy => 
    { 
        policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role,"admin");
    }); 
});
```

#### Demo

[image]

Comment: You're right, thanks for your help! Do you have any idea why `policy.RequireRole("admin")` doesn't work but `policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin")` does?

Comment: @levitatejay As far as I know, the `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role` is the standard way in dotnet core. However, although the transformation maps the role for us, it doesn't change the inner `_roleClaimType` field at the same time, which makes the `User.IsInRole()` unavailable, thus your `policy.RequireRole("admin")` doesn't work.

Comment: @itminus Thanks! Is there a way to fix it so RequireRole("admin") would work?

Comment: See here: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/14944

Answer (score 1):

You should also be able to achieve this without needing a policy. ASP.NET automatically maps common claims to the Microsoft schema.

When you inspect your access token. You will see you are sending the `role` claim. But when you look at the claims in the controller, you will notice that it has been transformed to `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role`.

There are two things you can do. Either set the `RoleClaimType` to `ClaimTypes.Role`. Like so:

```
services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(IdentityServerJwtConstants.IdentityServerJwtBearerScheme, options => {
    options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = ClaimTypes.Role;
});
```

Or tell the `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` not to map default inbound claims like this:
`JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;`

Since it's a static property this can be done at any time. But I set it somewhere during my service registrations.